# The reason why some get many answers and others get no answer at all

Tags: discussion, support

I wonder why I don't get answers to my questions. Are they too easy, too hard, too unreadable, too Special, too boring?

It's quite frustrating to ask questions and not getting an answer, looking at related question which have tons of answers.

Sometimes I get a comment and when I try to solve it with help of the comment, I don't get a further answer.. Sometimes I get an answer and if I ask some additional question, I don't get an answer. I don't know why, is this because I didn't get the obvious answer and the one that answered my question thinks I'm too stupid to get it and doesn't have the Patience to explain it to me?

would be quite cool if you could tell me why there could be so few answers to my questions such that I can make them more readable/... to get more answers.

Links to my questions:

[taylor Approximation of a discrete function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765909/taylor-approximation-of-a-discrete-function)
where I get no answer to my update after having received a comment

[error term of discrete taylor approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769757/error-term-for-discrete-taylor-expansion-newton-series-finite-differences)
no answer and no comment at all

[asymptotics of sum of binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767052/asymptotics-of-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-binomial-distribution-poisson-ap)
an answer but then no Response to my further questions

[reverse Distribution tails](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756447/reverse-distribution-tails)
no answer and no comment at all

[mean of a function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94917/mean-of-a-function-of-one-random-variable) no answer no comment

[taylor Expansion for mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94906/mean-of-a-transformation-of-a-random-variable-approximating-the-mean-by-taylor) no answer no comment

I think I really Show effort and am willing to solve some part on my own, but when I'm stuck, I'm stuck and then I would really appreciate some hint.

And I often get some (1,2) upvotes and sometimes some user mark my questions as favorite, so the questions can't be too bad?

Comment: I am the author of the only answer so far to [Asymptotics of sum ... Poisson approximation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767052/asymptotics-of-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-binomial-distribution-poisson-ap). I answered your first comment, then left your second comment unanswered, for the following reasons. 1. You seem too focused on your own (non working) approach to read and try to fully "digest" my answer. 2. My answer contains about everything valuable that can be said on your problem (I think). 3. You started adding again and again .../...

Comment: .../... new parts to the question and this is not how the site is supposed to work. I might be to blame for not explaining these things on the page but (i) I am only human and (ii) as already mentioned, I felt you were not really listening.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate that you tell me "your Problem" with my way to write/answer questions. My Explanation, if you want to hear it: 

1. I see that I first didn't get your answer and one can see that as me as "not really listening" but this is not because I want to be ignorant or I don't want to listen. It's because I am a beginner and sometimes it's difficult to me to fully understand the answers. (I don't even study mathematics..). I really try to understand your answer, but I might Need some additional help, sometimes.. .../...

Comment: .../... 2. I tried to adapt your answer, I calculated it, did some remodeling and then I wasn't sure how to get further. I were stuck there and I wans't sure whether I made a mistake or this is "all" I can get from it. So I am not sure why you think, that I didn't listen to your answer?

3. I added additional things to the question, thinking that it might help someone. I didn't know that this is not the way it works, so I in the future I won't do that.

so: it's great that People like you help us with our Problems. It's not that I don't see your effort. .../...

Comment: .../... It's really nice of you. And I'm really sorry if I give you or someone else the Feeling of not appreciating a solution or not listening to a solution.. That is not what I want to feel you. 
I am just a beginner who is too "stupid" to understand it without some additional help. 

In the future, I will try to adapt more to the answers and will not modify the question (add additional parts).

I hope this will make the users feel more happy about my Posts and maybe I may get some more answers.. 

thank you, did, for your help in this meta and in the main Forum!!

Comment: I had a look at some of the 6 questions. Two of them are on the stats website, not m.se, so I wouldn't expect anyone here to be able to tell you why they have no response. The other one I looked at was just posted 3 hours ago. 3 hours! Math is eternal! Have some patience!

Comment: I see that it might take some time to write an answer and that somehow 3 hours is nothing.

But when I then have a look at other questions which have so many answers in some minutes, I think the time is not a very important factor. Somehow it is even worse: the older your question is, the fewer clicks it gets and thus the fewer answers. I made the experience that if I don't get an answer in the first hours I will never get an answer, because the question will be "lost". But it might be, that I should be a Little bit more Patient. I'll try it.

Comment: Your reference to "other questions which have so many answers in some minutes" raises different problems than the ones you might think. To go further, one should know which kind of questions with many instant answers you have in mind--and then, to explain why things happen the way they happen would require time and care. To sum up, there are several reasons why some questions receive quickly many answers and not all of these reasons are commendable features of the site.

Comment: I have a similar problem. A few days ago I asked a question on sequences, which received 7 upvotes, but no response - quite strange. What might be the reason for that? (I started a bounty, so hopefully that'll help!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I looked at your first linked question, then I have read the comments and judge them to fully answer your question. Then I have had a look at your edit. It is long and I cannot see if there is even a question somewhere in there. If there were, it should be posted as a new question, anyway.

Then I look at your second linked question, it is very long, so I skip to the bolded part. I might be able to answer it if I thought seriously about it, but I am not convinced that it is the right question to ask in this context and I also notice that the part I skipped contains a lot of question marks, so very likely, my effort would be rewarded by you telling me that my answer does not answer the six other questions in your question.

So, now, given the fact that there are more questions than answers on this site, why should I spend any further time on your questions instead of answering other people's questions?

More importantly, why don't you go and answer some questions yourself to get a feel what kind of question is easy to understand.

Comment: You're wrong. As http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions shows, there are actually more answers than questions on this site. (But as a whole, I generally agree with the outlines of your point.)